# State only being altered once when repeatedly called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I'm trying to increase a timers interval so that it will start off fast, then gradually get slower. I've declared the state and a function that gets called when the time interval has been reached. the TimeInterval state should increase to 4 then the next time it's called 8, 16, 32 etc. For some reason though, it is only being called once and will get stuck on 4. RandomNumberGenerator() and RandomColorGenerator() are constantly updating. Any idea why TimeInterval gets stuck on 4?

```
    const [TimeInterval, setTimeInterval] = useState(2)
```

```
const NextSelection = () => {
        setTimeInterval(TimeInterval * 2)
        RandomNumberGenerator()
        RandomColorGenerator()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` hook update is an asynchronous operation.
Even though that is not the main issue here, the values held by the hook is the value on which it was closed over at the time the function was invoked. When the new value is dependent on previous value better to use the setter function since each render forms a closure over the variables

```
setTimeInterval(TimeInterval * 2)
```

to

```
setTimeInterval(latestTimeInterval => latestTimeInterval * 2)
```